# Disable IPv6 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, postfix, ipv6

Simple way that worked for a very long time was adding in **/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Afterwards **sysctl -p** for activation of the setting.
It works for a while, but suddenly the IPv6 is enabled.
We are facing two things:

1. IPv6 is randomly enabled
2. After restart of the server, IPv6 is enabled again.

Checking the proc:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/disable_ipv6
1
```

I want this disabled, there is a postfix server and gmail is objecting while IPv6 is active.

Comment: However, seems to be ok lately (few months already), I didn't figure out what was wrong. Maybe some ubuntu update fixed that.

Answer (score 14):

To permanently disable ipv6, you can update your grub file. You'll need administrative rights.

Edit /etc/default/grub with your preferred text editor. Make sure ipv6.disable=1 is added to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX lines as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

Then

```
sudo update-grub
```

And you should be good after a reboot.

Comment: Worked great for a few months, but now on 5.11.0-44 it still uses IPv6 even with setting ipv6.disable=1  :/

Comment: It is no issue with 5.11.0.44, I'm running the same and still disabled. Double check if nothing has changed your grub config...
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-ipv6-address-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa Also you can check if ipv6 is really disabled in different ways https://www.golinuxcloud.com/linux-check-ipv6-enabled/